# How to remove object from NSMutableArray in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I am trying to delete row of UITableView and removing the object from NSMutableArray. Here is my code for deleting row.

```
    [myArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

after this I am reloading my tableView.Using this Its delete that object.But, Problem is when I am running application second time that deleted object is showing again in tableview. How can I delete the object from array?? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is not with how you deleting the object from NSMutableArray. You might be updating the array again.

Comment: are you loading your tableview from your mutable array?

Comment: @newDev:is you initialized your array in cellforrowatindexpath

Answer (score 1):

i think you are re-initializing the array again , thats why it happening.

```
[myArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

surely this line removes the object from myArray. you can check this by help of breakpoint or NSLOg after this line execution

Answer (score 1):

Simply Check the Part of your **myArray Initialization**.

**1)** Check that your Initialization of myArray is called when you loads that particular view or Not !

**2)** Check for your `viewDidLoad` Method , if you have initialized your `myArray` there then the element will never be removed.

**Answer :** Use **Break Points** and `NSLogs`

Answer (score 0):

You have loaded the `myArray` from somewhere and now data is in RAM, deleting the object will remove it from RAM but it is already present at that place where you loaded that array. Remove from that place as well.

Answer (score -1):

First tell me ... Whence you get Array.. i mean from `database` or `plist` or `coredata` or `locally`?? if you locally create array in `viewDid` method and you get array item from it then it get all time of full list of array item as you created in `viewDid`.. if you get array from `database` or `plist` or `coredata` then send query(for database) or refere for plist and core data (for how to delete data )  `[tableView reloadData];` at end.